# Multiplicative inverse of infinite series- polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, field-theory, inverse

I believe there's a multiplicative inverse for the set of the series $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty x^i$.
If this is the case, how would I go about finding the multiplicative inverse? Otherwise, is there just not a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: What ring are you considering this series as an element of?  There normally isn't any sensible way to define a product of two power series that have both infinitely many positive powers and infinitely many negative powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S:=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty x^i$. You probably want $xS=S$ to hold, and this gives $(x-1)S=0$ which leads to $S=0$ and has no multiplicative inverse. Of course, this is assuming that the definition of $S$ makes sense. You need to specify a summation method for that because it diverges for all $x$.

Comment: It is important to note that the manipulation above is rigorous only at the level of formal series, if anything. The series diverges for any real or complex value of $x$.